# Condense python's json parse pretty print

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am using httpie for api requests. However, I do not at all like how big the spaces are and how the characters are separated. I get something like as follows from httpie

```
~ » http http://localhost:3000/api/orders
{
  "data": [
    {
      "_id": "xjqC28N5MPHRJQPho",
      "products": [
        {
          "count": 2,
          "days": [
            0,
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5,
            6
          ],
          "forkedFrom": "x7sRc23qPs3YcouS7",
          "name": "Spiderman Triple Action Web Blaster!"
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Ideally, I would like a more condensed format. Something akin to the following.

```
{
  "data": [{
    "_id": "xjqC28N5MPHRJQPho",
    "products": [{
      "count": 2,
      "days": [1,2,3,4,5,6],
      "forkedFrom": "x7sRc23qPs3YcouS7",
      "name": "Spiderman Triple Action Web Blaster!"
    }]
  }]
}
```

I noticed [httpie seems to use the python JSON parser](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie/blob/master/httpie/output/formatters/json.py).

Is it possible to format python's pretty print to be more condensed in format?

Comment: [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) takes a `cls` parameter to replace the default `JSONEncoder`; if you subclass this and implement your own `encode` method, you could patch in the (somewhat smarter) [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) functionality instead.